# "Subjective" heuristics a bit off?

Tags: support, subjective

How exactly does

[image: subjective]

appear subjective? I don't see anything subjective at all about that title, nor do I see any "hot button" words that might be taken as subjective, e.g. "best", "optimal", etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word `you` hits the system as a question that might be subjective.
Like `What do`**`you`**`think of windows?`

The system thinks that you are asking something that might garner opinion or be `subjective` when using the word  `you`

Try using `I`:
[image: no error :-)]

Or you can even try the following:
[image: no error as well :-)]

Comment: +1. Would checkmark, but apparently I need to wait 10 minutes.

Comment: @Billy kk :-) i added a screenshot as well.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like there needs to be more subjective words matched than *just* "you". I can think of a lot of questions that include the word "you" that are far from subjective.

Comment: @Cody -- that is true, but that seems to be the way the system works

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing about the validity of your answer.

Comment: @Cody I realize that. And this whole thing might lead into a question of a [meta-tag:feature-request], but most probably **not** from me

Comment: I get this message for every question I ask...it feels way to aggressive and "scary" for new users posting their first question...for instance a question like "how do you delete a metric in appdynamics" gets this stern warning about being subjective? huh?