# Can't use the word "question" in title in the context of "a security question implementation"

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, title, blocklist

I tried editing a question to have a more fitting title. The questions is about how to implement a password reset function by having a "security question" in a certain security framework. The title as it is now is not very useful, as it really doesn't describe the problem. I tried to change it to something along the lines of "How to reset password with security question in `<security framework>`?"

But I can't, I'm not allowed to use the word "question"!

I read this answer for [why it's not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114224/186983):

> Answer: Because it would be redundant and pointless.

But this doesn't apply here. The problem *is* about security *questions*, and I'm unable to add a descriptive title. I'd call that a bug.

Comment: "Security inquiry" :)

Comment: "security reminder"

Comment: "Security query." Also, what question?

Comment: Wow, three diamonds in a row. Honestly, while changing the verbiage slightly *does* work, these things *are* most commonly referred to as "security questions" AFAIK. Calling them something else in the title makes searching for these types of questions difficult.

Comment: Not for nothing, but why should we change the wording if that is the actual "inquiry" being "proffered?"  Worse, why is there such stubborn resistance to allowing a moderator (or even a high-rep user) to override the word ban if that is appropriate?  And no, questi0n is not a satisfactory workaround; it is a joke.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I closed and gave up on the question, but I found it again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508871/user-forgot-password-alternative-approach-in-spring
As GenericHolidayName says, this is a common name, having to refer to it by something else is problematic.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName The word "question" doesn't need to be in the title to show up in searches.

Comment: @TheGrinch I'm strongly in favor of letting mods/high-rep users override the word ban in the 1% of cases where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: It's probably not implemented because it breaks editing; if someone else comes along and edits the question, their edit will be blocked because it has a stop word in it, so ordinary editors would just have to remove the word again.

Comment: @Matsemann That question has a lot more problems than just lacking the work "question" in the title.  It seems to be ripe for closing as "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" at worst, and "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow..." at best.

Comment: @TheGrinch Gah!  You're right, that would be annoying.

Comment: @TheGrinch - But the same thing already happens with images without problems. Low rep users can't add them but they seem to be able to edit their questions fine if someone else inlines their link.

Comment: did there use to be an problem with too many users putting the word "question" in their titles?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug. The question you linked to explains why the ban is in place. You've just stumbled across one of the *very* few questions that legitimately demand that word be in the title.

Bear in mind that people come across questions only partly due to the title. Google (and presumably the SE search algorithms) will search the entirety of the page. So provided the title is something sensible like "security challenge" and there are lots of references to "security question" in the body of the post, it should be fine.

I think this feature provides more benefits than downsides. But there will always be exceptions where the rule doesn't appear to fit. Such is life.