# Ban "need help" from question titles on non-meta sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

I noticed many questions on SO that begin with ["I need help with", or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22need+help%22).

These questions are rarely good, because

- "I need help" is not a question.
- Well, duh. Otherwise, you wouldn't be on this site.
- It indicates that the problem is very narrow and maybe too specialized for this site.
- Most of the times, the title contains little further information about the actual problem.
- They often are of the "can you do my work?" variety.

It also seems like these questions have, on average, a low rating (0-2 votes).

Now, I don't say that "need help" in question titles should be *verboten*, but maybe a pop-up that warns you that you might be about to ask a bad question (maybe with useful link) could be helpful?

Many "need help" questions are asked by new members, so this might also be a chance to avoid that their first experience on SO is having a question down-voted into oblivion.

Comment: `help` is *already* mostly banned from question titles. It is not blacklisted outright but *is* part of a quality test, I believe.

Comment: As it is, when I see that in a title I know it's a bad question before I even step into it.  If you just remove that text I've lost my indicator that it's a bad question without actually fixing the question.

Comment: I just tried putting *I need help* in the title & nope, didn't get warned.

Comment: I don't think that the benefit from this feature is really worth the clutter that would come with it

Comment: do you realize the pr0b13m5 that automatic word filters normally bring?

Comment: word filters like this can result in [Unintended Consequences](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211136/cant-use-the-word-question-in-title-in-the-context-of-a-security-question-im).  You generally want to avoid them unless it gives you an actual and substantial benefit

Comment: @SamIam so why is it okay to ban "question" and not "help"?. I feel like both are equally degenerate in the average case, and both have fringe cases where they're okay. Whose rationale is drawing this line? Perhaps we can have a title review queue, where all questions with automatically detected bad titles are put. These reviews would be very easy and quick to review, so I don't think the queue would get overloaded.

Comment: @Cruncher Frankly, I'm against the filter on `"question"` and `"problem"` too.

Comment: @SamIam That's fair. So am I. But either way, as a community we need to decide whether we want filters or not. If we decide that we do, then we can't use the generic argument against filters against a particular filter.

Comment: @Cruncher Of course you can, in fact, if you are to use filters at all you **must** use the generic argument against all filters all the time.  Otherwise you wind up with too many filters, because... why not... and you might find yourself writing un-natural titles to your questions because they don't trigger filters.

Comment: @SamIam The problem is, that once it's decided that filters are fair game, whether or not a particular filter gets added becomes a game of "were the people that are against filters there to argue against this particular one at that time?". Just feels like it creates inconsistencies. For example, if you believed that opinion questions would be on topic on stackoverflow, doesn't particularly give you the right to try to reopen all of them. It's against what the community decided.

Comment: @Cruncher Of course you have the right to try and reopen those questions.  The rest of the community probably won't give the reopen votes too, but nobody is going to punish you for voting to reopen opinion questions.

Comment: @Cruncher and If in 2008-2009, we decided that whatever the community seemed to accept, we would just go with it, than opinion questions would probably still be considered to be good questions.

Comment: @SamIam Because somebody opened a topic about opinion questions in GENERAL. Not argued about a particular opinion question. I'm all for debate about filters in general, in which case I'd be on your side. I don't believe that doing so on a question about a specific filter, when other filters currently exist, is the place to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming all the facts are aligned with your assertion ('rarely good, because...'), It might make sense to flag them as low-quality posts so they could get some attention.  (And if you did that, we might actually come up with some measurables -- such as how many of them got a "looks good", versus how many needed to be edited or deleted).  But I'd not be ready, at least at this point, to support an outright ban on them.

Comment: A little effort with editing the offending title does seem more constructive than implementing a "ban".

Comment: The thing is, I don't want them to be flagged as bad questions, I would prefer to give the author a chance to improve the question before it is published.

Comment: @Arian -- I hear you -- but I guess my hedge is that at this point, it might be presumptive to consider them 'questions in need of improvement' based on a word in the title.  Not saying you're wrong -- just that we need more data.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just answer my own question to show a possible solution to the problem:

When a user (with less than 500 Rep?) asks a question that contains the words "need help" (or a variation thereof) and submits, the following warning pops up:

> It seems like your question has room for improvement.
>   Avoid phrases like "I need help" and try to describe your problem instead.
>   Here is a guide on asking good questions: `<link in new tab>`
>
> [ Improve this question ]
>   [ Submit as is ]

This concept can be extended to other keywords and customized to fit other sites.
For instance, when a question contains "career", the warning might suggest to move the question to programmers.SE.